# SpEL templates mixing expressions and literals

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

how can i parse a "complex" template-like SpEL expression that mixes literal text and actual #{SpEL expressions}?  for example:

```
the dog says #{dog.getSound()}
```

Apache Camel supports this template-like capability in its expression languages (including SpEL), but i haven't been able to root out how to accomplish this directly with vanilla SpEL.

Comment: just found the answer - not yet at a hundred reputation, so i'll post tomorrow when the 8h timer runs out: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html#d0e12128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as described in the [user guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html#d0e12128), evaluate the Expression in a [TemplateParserContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/common/TemplateParserContext.html):

```
String randomPhrase = 
    parser.parseExpression("random number is #{T(java.lang.Math).random()}", 
                      new TemplateParserContext()).getValue(String.class);

// evaluates to "random number is 0.7038186818312008"
```